# check if a file exists in a folder actionScript 3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, directory

I would like to check if the file exists and if not display noimage.gif. The below is returning false in the console, can you help?

```
 ...
[Bindable]
private var imageName:String;   
imageName  = "pca" + this._product.productID + ".jpg";

var fileName:File = new File() 
fileName.nativePath = "C:/STSMultimediaSync/market/pictures/{imageName}"; 
trace(fileName.exists);
....
```

PS - I know the file exists as when I hard code the image name, the value changes to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do {} inside AS3 (It can be done in mxml). Try :

```
fileName.nativePath = "C:/STSMultimediaSync/market/pictures/"+imageName;
```

Comment: @Baris Usakli - you're right that worked.  Glad I asked now. Newbie eyes!